# Calculate number of needed simulations

Tags: statistical-significance, experiment-design, simulation

First I have to apologize for any uncorrect naming or categorisation of my question, as I am an electrical engineer rather than a mathematican.

I have a simulation that outputs for a given number of input parameters one output value. As the simulation is pretty complicated, I don't know the statistical connection between input and output. I can run the simulation with different seeds to produce different outputs for the same input (it depends on some random numbers).

**How do I choose the number of simulations I have to run with the same input, but different seeds to make sure I get significant results?**

Perhaps make 10 simulations, calculate the deviation and with this deviation I can calculate the real number of needed simulations?

Edit1: Some more pieces of information: the simulation is a traffic simulation. I have input parameters (like 70% of all cars are minivans or 60% of all junctions are controlled by traffic lights). And I have output values (fuel consumption). Some internal decissions depend on random numbers (when a traffic light turns green, what route to take, ...).

I want to know how many different seeds for the PRNG I have to choose, to make the output at least a bit "sure".

Edit2: Some more general pieces of information: You know my setup, and the output (fuel consumption). Now I want to check, how the fuel consumption depends on the number of minivans in the city. So I change this number from 0% to 100%. Because there are some random parts in the simulation, you don't get a nice curve, but one with a few outliers. So I thought: Ok, run it 5 times with different seeds and take the mean of all 5. And voila, I get a smooth curve.

This number 5 was just guessed by me. It looks good in the graph, but has no mathematical background. But perhaps some of you could help me with this. Thanks!

Comment: Didn't know there is stats - would anyone move/migrate my question?

Comment: Your question is now migrated to the statistics.SE site. There will be a link that appears below the question here that you can follow to the new location of your question. If you need help associating an account on statistics.SE, you can flag your question for moderator attention, and someone over there will help out.

Comment: @ZevChonoles: Thank you, but I think I'll be fine. Now I am looking forward to receiving some help on the question itself ;)

Comment: **What is the purpose of this simulation?** Different purposes will have (hugely) different answers.  For instance, they could plausibly include (1) testing inputs for influence in the outputs, (2) reliably predicting the output for future inputs, (3) identifying global extrema of the output, (4) developing scientific theories about the system being simulated, and (5) comparing the simulation to the results of another system or simulation.

Comment: Bill Huber is absolutely right.  Give us your specific goals and what type of output variable you are looking at.  I may still be possible to estimate or bound the Monte Carlo variance and even though you are stricted to a small number of simulations you can see how that variance bound changes with increased number of simulations and then you can trade off accuracy versus practical computing time. Another thought for consideration are variation reduction techniques  Among the possibilities are control variates, antithetic variates and importance sampling.

Comment: What if any of these techniques are available for you depends on your application.  A great description of the variance reduction techniques that I recommend is still Hammersley and Handscombe's "Monte Carlo Methods" a Methuen Monograph from the 1950s.  If it is still in print Chapman and Hall/ CRC would be the current publisher.  A really nice book with examples showing the complexity and applications of Monte Carlo in the pharmaceutical industry setting is Mark Chang's "Monte Carlo Simulation for the Pharmaceutical Industry published by Chapman and Hall/CRC in 2011.

Comment: Some of these variance reduction techniques are covered in Section 2.3 of Chang's book.  Another source that is still in print (possibly in 2nd edition) is J. R. Thompson's book "Simulation" published by Wiley.

Comment: @MichaelChernick and whuber: I just added some information in the question above. I hope this helps ;)

Comment: Thanks, powerbar, that helps: but you still haven't told us *why* you are conducting these simulations and what you hope to learn from them.  That's the crucial matter.

Comment: @powerbar I don't think there is an answer to your question.  Certainly you have to specify what you mean by a bit "sure".  The objective as Bill Huber said is still not clear. If the output is an estimate it may be that you want the variance to be small.  In that case it means that you need to quantify samll with a number. In Bayesian MCMC analyses the objective is to get a posterior distribution.

Comment: So there you need enough simulations so that the entire distribution of output values is close in some specific sense to the Bayesian posterior distirbution which is the distribution that the set of outputs is converging to.  These are very different problems with very different answers and each requires very specific definitions of what "close" means.

Comment: @MichaelChernick Thank you so much for all your help, I just added another bit of information. I hope this time, it helps!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I try to summarize all answers by you in order to have a single place for everything important.

Steps to calculate the needed number of simulations:

1. Run the simulation with a default number of runs $R_0$. I've seen $R_0 = 1000$ most of the times. Now you should have a vector with the results $x_0$ where $length(x_0) = R_0$.
2. Calculate the mean value $\overline{x}_0$ and the standard deviation $s_0$.
3. Specify the allowed level of error $\epsilon$ and the uncertainty $\alpha$ you are willing to accept. Normally you choose $\epsilon = \alpha = 0.05\%$.
4. Use this equation to get the required number of simulations:
   $R \geq (\frac{Z_{1-(\alpha / 2)} \cdot s_0}{\epsilon \cdot \overline{x}_0})^2$, where $Z_{1-(\alpha / 2)}$ is the $1 − (\alpha /2)$ quantile of the standard normal distribution.
5. [Use the student-t-distribution rather than the normal distribution for small $R_0$]

I hope this will help everybody who will look for an answer.

Comment: Powerbar, answering your own question and accepting it are fine. For the discussion about this, please see [this thread](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463) in the SE FAQ.

Answer (score 4):

This question is more difficult to answer than you imagine.  It depends on the input, the output and degree of precision required on the output.  One thing to do is add say $100$ simulations to the current number and if the results seem not to have changed much there could be sufficient convergence.  If not keep going until you converge.  This assumes that as the input distributions become representative the output distribution will be well represented or if the output is a estimate it will have come close to converging to its expected value.  The simplest case is when the output is a single proportion that is a binomial proportion. Then the variance for the output has variance bounded by $\frac{1}{4n}$ where $n$ is the number of simulations.  Then you can take n large enough so that the variance of the estimator is as small as you would require.  This may seem like an unusual situation.  But it comes up a lot when comparing estimation technique.  For example I have done simulations to compare bootstrap confidence interval methods.  To see if the actual confidence level close to what it is suppose to be we simulate sampling from a particular population distribution and compute the proportion of times the interval includes the true parameter.  We might want the standard deviation of the estimate to be less than say $0.001$. This can be achieved since the standard deviation is the square root of the variance and is less than $\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{n}}$ So this will be achieved if we take $n> \frac{4}{(0.001)^2}$.

Comment: I do understand that this is pretty complicated ;) Each run of the simulation takes quite a bit (days!), so I really can't just run 1000 simulations. But I do need some kind of verification of my number, even it is quite low :-/

Answer (score 0):

Powerbar, this answer is to address your last comment.  Perhaps you can think of your simulation as representing a model for fuel consumption as a function of % minivans on the road plus a random noise component.  So every time you run the simulation you get a slightly distorted picture of the curve because of the additive noise component. Each simulation is giving you at various % minivans simulated the value of the function + a random component. If the simulations are independent and the random components are independent (a very reasonable assumption) then averaging the values at each % minivan will improve the estimate of the "actual" fuel consumption value because the average reduces the variance of the noise by a factor of 1/n at each point.  In your case choosing 5 reduces it by a factor of 1/5.  The standard deviation is reduced by a factor of 1/sqrt(5) or 1/2.236.  So the variation from the curve is 2.236 times smaller for the averaged data.  Had you used 3 or 4 it would have helped also but not as much.  For n larger than 5 would help even more but may not be necessary since your eye saw satisfactory smoothness.

Comment: Hi Michael, I did understand this answer. This is why I ran the simulation more than once ;) But is there a statistical way to know how big n has to be, aside from my eye? That is my real question...

Comment: @powerbar My second answer explains precisely how increased sample size reduces the variance of the estimate.  So you can pick n to be large enough so that the variance is smaller than a value you specify as small enough.  In my first answer I showed that taking n>4/(0.001)$^2$ is a number that can be used for a binomial response variable.  In other cases σ$^2$/n is the variance of the mean.  So requiring it to be less than c means taking n> σ$^2$/c.  like in the case of the binomial if you know an upper bound on σ$^2$ you can use that to get n.

Comment: Otherwise do a small simulation to get an esimate of σ$^2$ and use that to choose n.  This is not perfect but it should give you a good idea of what n needs to be.